# Picking data inside a string via reflex

Tags: c#, regex

Okay i have been trying to pick some data from a string with reflex(in c#) for a while, basically i want to pick everything between Customer and <\div> but i dont seem to be able to get the data:
my code:

```
   string text= "<div> Company = Fake Company </div><div>Customer: XXXX</div><div>Device: NY-FIL05 </div><div>Service: Device     Fail:</div> "
   var groups= Regex.Match(text, @"Customer: (.*\b</\div>\b")).Groups;
   var auxi = groups[1].Value;
```

basically i need to grab XXXX but im  always either grabbing everything or grabbing nothing

Comment: HTML is not a regular language, so regex will always be the wrong choice.  Use HTMLAgilityPack instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string text = "<div> Company = Fake Company </div><div>Customer: XXXX</div><div>Device: NY-FIL05 </div><div>Service: Device     Fail:</div>";
Match m = Regex.Match(text, @"(?<=Customer: ).*?(?=</div>)");
if (m.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

Explanation:

```
(?<=Customer: ).*?(?=</div>)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/c25yrj99pRe6D64Q)

Comment: looks like it worked great ty, but is the first ?<= in ?<=Customer: necesary? i dont need to look behind it, wouldnt Customer: work?

Comment: @Damian `?<=` - it is positive lookbehind, see the updated answer. Of course if you need `Customer: ` part to be included into the match too, then you can use `Customer: .*?(?=</div>)` regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
var groups=  Regex.Match(text, @"Customer: ([\w ]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

**Note:**
You missed the closing quote in `string text`

Comment: that works if the Customer is just 1 word, if for example its: XX PP, it will only get XX, instead of XX PP, im trying to find a way to get everything no matter what is inside, you are right didnt notice ty

Comment: @Damian Based on your comment, I've updated my answer.